# Are there any commentaries on Saraswati sahastra naamas?

Tags: saraswati, commentary, telugu

[Lalitha sahastra naamavali](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Lalitha_Sahasranamam) (1000 names of Lalitha) is present in Brahmanda Purana. It is popular and has some Telugu commentaries like [Sowbhagya Bhaskara Bhashyam](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLj9wh7jh7ReqqSCalZh4BPYLzG25nQIjH).

[Saraswathi sahastranaamam](https://stotram.co.in/maha-saraswati-sahasranama-stotram/) is present in Skanda purana. I want to read some commentaries on those names if available.

Are there any commentaries available for any Saraswathi sahastranaamas also? I am interested in the Telugu language. If no such work is available in Telugu, then the English language can be okay.

Comment: Why did the bot delete this Q? Any idea?

Comment: @Rickross Yeah, if less activity or comments, questions will be deleted automatically.